# Detectar si en un texto si hay un espacio después de la coma (En C)

Tags: c, string

Llevo todo el día buscando información sobre como se puede afrontar este problema pero no logro que funcione de ninguna de las maneras que he intentado.

Necesito que el código lea un texto acabado en un punto (.) y que de este texto detecte si después de una coma, hay un espacio. Por ejemplo:

"Hola, buenos días." sería correcto.

"Hola,buenos días." sería incorrecto.

Esto es la última versión de mi código la cual no detecta la coma ni el espacio. Que lea el  fgets después de escanearlo es simplemente para comprobar que lo ha leído bien.

```
char c[100];
char * pc;
printf("Enter the text\n");
fgets(c,100, stdin);
printf("%s",c);
while (* c != '.')
{

    if (*c == ',' && *c == ' ')
    {
        printf("\nThere is a space after a comma\n");

    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nThere isn't a space after a comma\n");
    }
    fgets(c,100, stdin);
}

return 0;
```

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código actual básicamente no hace lo que planteas, te propongo una solución sencilla:

Un snippet para leer desde `stdin`:

```
int leer_stdin(char *_c, int len) {
  if (!_c)
    return len;
  int chr = 0;
  while (len > 0) { 
    chr = fgetc(stdin);
    if (chr == EOF || chr == '\n')
      return ((*_c) = 0), len;
    (*_c) = chr;
    --len; ++_c;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Y en tu función `main`:

```
#define MAX_LEN (100)

int main(void) {
  char c[MAX_LEN], *pc; int fail = 0;

  printf("Ingrese una linea: ");
  leer_stdin(c, MAX_LEN); pc = c;

  while (pc && *pc) {
    if (*pc == '.')
      break;
    else if (*pc == ',' && *(pc + 1) != ' ') {
      fail = 1; break;
    }
    ++pc;
  }

  printf("\nThere %s a space after a comma\n", (fail)? "isn't": "is");

  return 0;
}
```

Básicamente lo que hace este código es:

- Leer todos los caracteres desde `stdin` hasta llegar a los 100 caracteres o encontrar un salto de linea.
- Luego itera la cadena resultante buscando un `.` o un caracter nulo.
- Si encuentra una `,` y el siguiente caracter no es un espacio, entonces se detendrá y pondrá `fail` a `1` para indicar que no había un espacio en la sentencia.
- Si encuentra una `,` y el siguiente caracter es un espacio, entonces se continua la iteración hasta encontrar un `.`.

Si tu sentencia introducida no termina en `.`, entonces se detendrá al encontrar un caracter nulo.

Aquí te dejo un [repl.it](https://repl.it/@IamNaCl/SurprisedOilyApplescript), saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

c tiene una funcion llamada strstr que sirve justamente para encontrar strings adentro de strings, hice un ejemplo que podria serte util:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRING_SIZE 101

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    char   c[STRING_SIZE];
    char * pos;
    int    len;
    int    comma_count;

    printf("Enter the text\n");

    memset(c,0,STRING_SIZE);

    fgets(c,STRING_SIZE,stdin);

    //Verificamos que el string este terminado por un punto
    pos = strstr(c,".");

    if( pos && (c - pos) < STRING_SIZE ){
        pos[1] = '\n';
    }else{
        printf("String not properly ended\n");
        return 0;
    }

    len = strlen(c);

    pos = c;
    comma_count = 0;
    while(pos < c + len){

        //Buscamos la siguiente coma en el string
        pos = strstr(pos ,",");

        if(!pos){
            //Si no hay comas sale del bucle
            if(!comma_count){
                printf("there are no commas\n");
            }

            break;
        }

        //Llevamos cuenta de las comas
        comma_count++;

        //Verifica cual es el caracter que continua la coma
        if(pos[1] == ' '){
            printf("\nThere is a space after a comma, in position %d\n",pos - c);
        }
        else{
            printf("\nThere is a comma without a space, in position %d\n",pos - c);
        }
        pos++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```