# Punteros a cadenas dinamicas

Tags: c, string

-Lo que queria hacer no lo he podido implementar, es que al pedir un nombre y apellido al usuario a priori NO SABEMOS cual va a ser la longitud de stdin que teclee el usuario. En la linea del malloc puse 10 por poner como pude haber puesto 20 pero en realidad no se cuanto va a ocupar el nombre y el apellido que me ingrese el usuario por teclado no se como implementarlo de tal manera que cuando se teclee un nombre y un apellido se calcule la longitud y luego ya reservar memoria para esa longitud a parte tambien para reservar la memoria justa y necesaria para lo que me teclee el usuario y no andar a ciegas suponiendo que va ingresar un nombre y apellido de 10,20,30 etc bytes

-Como no me salio hice esto que no se parece en nada a lo que queria hacer en un principio y que aun por encima no consigo hacer que funcione como quiero
Espero haberme explicado con claridad y gracias

> Primera duda, porque el codigo no funciona como deberia? culpa del fgets?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char *nombre,*nombre2;
    nombre=malloc(10*sizeof(char)); //reservo 10 bytes
    printf("Introduce tu nombre y apellido: ");

    fgets(nombre,9,stdin); //agrega NULL y \n si se ingresan menos caracteres
    if (nombre[strlen(nombre)-1] == '\n'){
        nombre[strlen(nombre)-1] = '\0';
    }

    printf("%s\n",nombre);

    long int longitud=(strlen(nombre)+1); //strlen no cuenta el NULL de final de cadena
    printf("%li\n",longitud);

    if(longitud>8){
       nombre2=realloc(nombre,15*sizeof(char)); //reasigno 5 bytes
       printf("%s\n",nombre);
       free(nombre2);

     }
     free(nombre);


    return 0;
}
```

> Segunda duda, seria posible implementarlo?

Con respecto a la idea si alguien conoce python el codigo que quiero implementar en c seria algo asi en python:

```
while(1):
    cadena=str(input("Introduce lo que quieras o exit para salir: "))

    if(cadena=="exit"):
        break
    print(cadena)
```

Comment: Qué error te da?

Comment: Compila bien pero la parte del if basicamente no funciona bien, el printf dentro del if me imprime 9 bytes lo que es culpa del fgets pero no se como implementarlo de otra manera

Comment: El snippet de código en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/153299/4499) te puede servir bastante para leer cuantos bytes necesites desde `stdin`.

Comment: gracias voy a mirar

Comment: Pero en ese code especificas el maximo que vas a leer #define MAX_LEN (100)

Comment: Listo. (Relleno)

Comment: @eduu15 Lo que quieres hacer lo hace una función llamada `getline()`. En [este repositorio](https://github.com/ivanrad/getline/blob/master/getline.c) tienes una posible implementación, para que veas cómo lo consigue. Básicamente lee caracteres de 1 en 1 y los va guardando en un buffer (que obtuvo con `malloc()`, de tamaño 128), y si el buffer se llena, lo amplía con `realloc()`, duplicandole el tamaño). Cuando el caracter leído es `\n` (o detecta EOF), da por terminada la lectura (no reajusta, por cierto, el buffer, que será en general mayor de lo necesario).

Comment: @abulafia gracias por el comentario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu problema es que quieres leer cuantos bytes quieras desde `stdin`, entonces te sugiero aprender sobre las funciones para pedir memoria dinámica al SO, este snippet es una modificación de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/153299/4499):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_MULT (120)
char *leer_stdin(void) {
  int chr = 0, mult = 0, len = 0; 
  char *_c = NULL;

  while (1) {
    chr = fgetc(stdin);

    if (chr == EOF || chr == '\n') /* Detente solo si terminamos o si es final de linea */
      break;

    if (mult >= len) { /* pide más memoria si es necesario. */
      char *tmp = realloc(_c, mult + MAX_MULT);
      if (!tmp) /* si fall al pedir memoria, entonces detente ahora */
        break;
      _c = tmp, mult += MAX_MULT;
    }

    _c[len++] = chr; /* finalmente asigna. */
  }

  if (len)
    _c[len] = 0; /* pon el caracter nulo al final si no es NULL nuestra cadena */
  return _c; /* finalmente, devuelvela. */
}
#undef MAX_MULT
```

La función que te pongo aquí, coloca toda la memoria que necesite para leer desde `stdin`, luego de esto, debes liberarla con `free` y seguir la ejecución de tu programa.

En tu segunda 'duda' mencionas:

> ¿Será posible hacer la idea?

C es un lenguaje de programación, como cualquier otro puede realizar tareas dentro de lo que puede..? ¿Esto que propones? Es de lo más sencillo:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  while (1) {
    printf("Escribe algo: ");
    char *t = leer_stdin();
    if (t) {
      printf("Escribiste: '%s'\n", t);
      if (0 == strcmp(t, "salir")) { 
        free(t); break;
      }
      free(t);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

El código de arriba va a leer una cadena y a imprimir su contenido, obtenido de la función `leer_stdin()` y lo evaluará contra la cadena `"salir"` si son iguales *(Si retorna cero)*, entonces para la ejecución del programa.

> Nota: si vas a poner ambos fragmentos de código en el mismo archivo, asegurate de poner todas las directivas `#include` y posteriormente una declaración adelantada o la definición de la función `leer_stdin()` para que funcione correctamente.

Saludos!

Comment: Pero `fgets()` [sí que añade un nulo](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/).

Comment: @abulafia tienes razon

Comment: fgets añade un /0 al terminar la cadena y un salto de linea si se ingresan menos caracteres

Comment: @NaCI lo primero gracias por elaborar una respuesta y lo segundo en el code que pusiste estas estableciendo un limite 
#define MAX_MULT (120) si mal no entendi el codigo, y yo no quiero establecer un limite ahi el esta el quiz de la cuestion. En el codigo de python no hay un limite de bytes se van reservando dinamicamente segun se necesiten y es lo que quiero hacer yo

Comment: @abulafia gracias por el ojo, lo cambio en un momento. eduu15, has probado el código para decir que se limita a 120 caracteres? El código lo que hace es que si llega a 120 caracteres, pide mas memoria y sigue leyendo hasta volver a toparse con el nuevo límite.

Comment: Me pudo el ansia @NaCI

Comment: @NaCI si pones algo inferior a 120 por ejemplo "hola" no estarias desperdiciando unos cuantos bytes de memoria mientras el programa se esta ejecutando?

Comment: He cambiado el titulo de la pregunta pero no se si estara bien porque en realidad seria apuntadores a caracteres dinamicos si no me equivoco

Comment: Lo volvi a cambiar ahora creo que el titulo esta bien y es mas claro corrijanme si me equivoco

Comment: Si pones algo inferior a 120 se colocan 120 caracteres, pero es tu decisión si quieres liberar la memoria sobrante cuando sepas la longitud final del puntero, un desperdicio de instrucciones a mi parecer, pero si te es un problema los bytes que puedes desperdiciar, ajusta el `MAX_MULT` a un valor menor y listo, aunque en mi opinión... Con 64-bits quién se preocupa por 2 o 3 bytes de más?

Comment: entiendo, @NaCI crees que el titulo esta bien?

Comment: Seria punteros a caracteres dinamicos o arrays de caracteres dinamicos?

Comment: O cual le pondrias tu @NaCI

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es crear un `buffer` estático que te permita alojar todos los datos recogidos por consola y, posteriormente, creas el puntero del tamaño oportuno y le asignas el valor correspondiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAMANIO_MAXIMO_BUFFER 255

int main(void){
    char buffer[TAMANIO_MAXIMO_BUFFER] = {'\0'};
    char *nombre;

    //nombre=malloc(10*sizeof(char)); //reservo 10 bytes
    printf("Introduce tu nombre y apellido: ");
    fgets(buffer, TAMANIO_MAXIMO_BUFFER, stdin); //agrega NULL y \n si se ingresan menos caracteres

    if (buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] == '\n'){
        buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';
    }

    nombre = malloc(strlen(buffer)*sizeof(char)); //reservo el tamaño necesario
    strcpy(nombre, buffer); //copio al puntero nombre el nombre recibido

    printf("%s\n",nombre);

    long int longitud=(strlen(nombre)+1); //strlen no cuenta el NULL de final de cadena
    printf("%li\n",longitud);

     free(nombre);
     nombre = NULL; //siempre es bueno setear a NULL un puntero que no va a volver a ser usado

    return 0;
}
```

Si lo quieres hacer entero con memoria dinámica puedes hacer algo como ésto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAMANIO_MAXIMO_BUFFER 254

int main(void){
    char *nombre = malloc((TAMANIO_MAXIMO_BUFFER+1)*sizeof(char));
    char *nombre2;

    //nombre=malloc(10*sizeof(char)); //reservo 10 bytes
    printf("Introduce tu nombre y apellido: ");
    fgets(nombre, TAMANIO_MAXIMO_BUFFER, stdin); //agrega NULL y \n si se ingresan menos caracteres

    if (nombre[strlen(nombre)-1] == '\n'){
        nombre[strlen(nombre)-1] = '\0';
    }

    nombre2 = realloc(nombre, strlen(nombre)*sizeof(char));
    if (nombre2 != NULL){
        nombre = nombre2;
    } else {
        printf("ERROR, no se puede reasignar la memoria");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%s\n",nombre);

    long int longitud=(strlen(nombre)+1); //strlen no cuenta el NULL de final de cadena
    printf("%li\n",longitud);

     free(nombre);
     nombre = NULL; //siempre es bueno setear a NULL un puntero que no va a volver a ser usado
     free(nombre2);
     nombre2 = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: gracias por el code @JuMoGar

Comment: @eduu15 De nada. Veo que eres nuevo en la comunidad StackOverFlow. Te comento: Cuando una respuesta es útil es conveniente agradecerlo dándo a la flechita_arriba, independientemente de que tu hayas formulado (o no) la pregunta. Si has formulado una pregunta y te ha resuelto el problema, como agradecemiento igual, se da click al tick verde que aparece debajo de las flechitas_ariba_abajo. Por supuesto, recomendarte también leer cómo funciona la comunidad, cómo formular preguntas/respuestas, etc... Te será muy util de cara al futuro. Un saludo.